# Certificate based authentication

Tags: java, authentication, certificate, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

I'm planning to do a desktop app for secure file exchange in Java.
The app needs a reliable authentication method that must guarantee that only authorised users access the system.

In the registration, the users generate a key pair and send their username and public key to the central server of the system. A system admin, which has access to this central server, approves the registration and asks a certificate authority to issue a public key certificate that binds the username to the public key. A x509 certificate is generated and stored at a certificate server.

When the user wants to authenticate, he enters his username and the app creates a digital signature for him, with his private key. This signature is sent to central server, which requests the x509 certificate for the matching private key. If a x509 is found at the certificate server, it sends the certificate for the central server and the user is authenticated.

I think I have the correct idea, but I don't know how to start the implementation in Java. Can you guys give me a few pointers, or correct my ideas if you think I'm a little confused?

Comment: You are asking about implementation so I'm voting to migrate this to SO.

Comment: Why are you building a new authn protocol instead of using TLS or SSH, both of which can do cert authn? Why not just either store valid, authz'd certs on the service server or allow signed certs and manage a revocation list? You authn client to key server but it doesn't seem to anything else... How does the client authn key server? How does client authn service server? How does service server authn key server? How does key server authn service server?  What do you do to prevent replay of a signature? Why do you need the intermediate server to store the x509 cert instead of storing it?

Comment: This is a college project, and we aren't supposed to use TLS or SSH, i think. Anyway, I got your point, I should store authorised certificates in the central server. A client would be able to authenticate the central server because this central server also has a certificate issued by the same CA. The protocol I should use is Station-to-Station.

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, I don't really see the point of having a certificate authority sign an x509 certificate. It feels needlessly complicated since there isn't a need for a chain of trust.

Instead, I'd look into using something like SSH keys for authentication like what git does.

Comment: In file exchange involving two users, they request the x509 certificate of each other to the central server and exchange signatures, so they can be sure they're communicating with someone who is part of the system (protection against MITM). Thats why I need the CA.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Terry Chia that client auth SSL will give you a fast and easy way to get what you want.  Configure your web server with SSL and specifically client authentication, and provide the trusted CAs that the admin will use for signing approved certs.

The Java app will need to use an SSL library and have access to the way to set the credential for the library.  I think the default libary for SSL in Java may even do this, and may use the X509Certificate as a way to specify the credential.

What strikes me as odd in your description is that the client is not sending its certificate with the proof of private key (whether you sign it or use SSL, there is a proof of private key as either the signature or the SSL handshake).  It's far more typical to have the client say "This is who I am, and here is proof" - ie provide both the X509 Certificate and the proof of private key.  I suspect that the server *could• lookup the credential based on the public key, but it would be less efficient.